# On Linux I can't access HID (HOG) device using BlueZ in my application

Tags: linux, bluetooth, hid, bluez

In my application I can find my Bluetooth LE device with HOG support, however if I connect to the device it does not find the HID (HOG = HID over GATT) service and corresponding characteristics. There seem to be some input nodes in the Linux system.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service` and change to:

```
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=input,hog
```

Then Bluetooth daemon won't grab input or hog devices and won't create system input nodes. Then the HID GATT service and corresponding characteristics are available via BlueZ to application.